Frankenphp continuously sending requests to /
I'm trying Frankenphp with the Symfony app for the first time. Im using dunglas/frankenphp docker image as a base and extending it (shortened version of Dockerfile)
FROM dunglas/frankenphp:1.2-php8.2-alpine as base

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && install-php-extensions \
    @composer \
    apcu-stable \
    intl-stable \
    opcache-stable \
    pcntl-stable \
    pdo_pgsql-stable \
    pgsql-stable \
    redis-stable \
    zip-stable;

WORKDIR /src/app/

FROM base as common

COPY ../composer.json /src/app/composer.json
COPY ../composer.lock /src/app/composer.lock

WORKDIR /src/app/

FROM common as test

COPY --chown=daemon:daemon frankenphp/caddy/Caddyfile /etc/caddy/Caddyfile <--- copy Caddy config
COPY --from=common --chown=daemon:daemon /src/app/ /src/app
COPY --chown=daemon:daemon .. /src/app/

RUN install-php-extensions \
   pcov-stable  \
   xdebug-3.2.2;

RUN cp ${PHP_INI_DIR}/php.ini-development ${PHP_INI_DIR}/php.ini

USER daemon:daemon

RUN composer install \
   --no-interaction \
   --no-progress \
   --verbose \
   -d tools;

RUN composer install \
   --no-interaction \
   --no-progress \
   --verbose; \
   composer run-script install-codestandards

USER root:root

my Caddyfile looks like this:
{
    {$CADDY_GLOBAL_OPTIONS}

    frankenphp {
        worker public/index.php
    }

    auto_https off
}

{$CADDY_EXTRA_CONFIG}

api.local.me {
    root * public/
    encode zstd br gzip

    {$CADDY_SERVER_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}

    php_server
}


and in my docker-compose service described like:
api-frankenapp:
    build:
      context: ./src/products-data-api
      dockerfile: ./frankenphp/Dockerfile
      target: test
      args:
        - COMPOSER_AUTH=$COMPOSER_AUTH
    container_name: api_frankenapp
    volumes:
      - ./src/products-data-api/:/srv/app/:rw
      - api-app-cache:/src/app/var/cache
      - api-app-assets:/src/app/public/bundles
    expose:
      - 80
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - api.local.me

I also have added runtime/frankenphp-symfony composer pachege and extend composer file with:
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.3.*"
        },
        "runtime" : {
            "class": "Runtime\\FrankenPhpSymfony\\Runtime"
        }
    }

and when I'm running the docker container, in container logs I see it spawning multiple requests to / in the loop, and of course response is 404.
What I'm doing wrong? Why does the app itself spawn these requests in the loop without any user interaction??
